# No such method exception when creating a wiremock stub

Tags: java, spring-boot, wiremock

I have created a method that mocks an external API.

```
public final void mockApiWithRequestBody(ExternalAPI externalApi, String requestBody, String statusCode,
                                         String responseBody) {
            WireMock.stubFor(
            request(externalApi.method.toString(), urlPathEqualTo(externalApi.uri.toString()))
            .withRequestBody(equalToIgnoreCase(requestBody))
            .willReturn(aResponse()
                    .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .withStatus(Integer.parseInt(statusCode))
                    .withBody(responseBody)));
}
```

ExternalAPI is an Emum like so:

```
public enum ExternalAPI {
   ExternalAPI(HttpMethod method, String uri) {
      this.method = method;
      this.uri = uri;
   }
   public final HttpMethod method;
   public final String uri;
}
```

After I make a call to mockApiWithRequestBody, I am getting the exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.google.common.collect.FluentIterable 
com.google.common.collect.FluentIterable.from(java.lang.Object[])'
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.matching.StringValuePattern.getName(StringValuePattern.java:54)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.matching.ContentPattern.<init>(ContentPattern.java:29)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.matching.StringValuePattern.<init>(StringValuePattern.java:31)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.matching.AnythingPattern.<init>(AnythingPattern.java:23)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.matching.AnythingPattern.<init>(AnythingPattern.java:27)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.matching.UrlPattern.<clinit>(UrlPattern.java:24)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.urlPathEqualTo(WireMock.java:330)
at functional.steps.Steps.mockApi(Steps.java:174)
```

Not able to figure out what's wrong.
The exception occurs at request(externalApi.method.toString(), urlPathEqualTo(externalApi.uri.toString())).

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by using a different version of Wiremock (wiremock-jre8) since I was using Java 11.
Refer to - https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock/issues/940
and - https://wiremock.org/docs/download-and-installation/